# Point of intersection between two exponentials with a constant term

Tags: exponential-function

Is there any way to solve algebraically for $x$:

$a^x - b^x = C$

If not, is there a commonly used function that can be used to represent its solution?
e.g., the Lambert W function for $a^x - bx = C$

Answer (score 0):

General Method: Using Wolfram Alpha, to plot the graphs of: $y_1 = a^x-b^x, y_2 = C$, and locate the approximate intersection point(s).